# Easily switch between different multi-monitor setups (Windows XP)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display

I carry my laptop between a variety of work environments, each of which has a particular external monitor setup. For example:

- At work: 1680 x 1050 external monitor on my left
- In meeting room: 1900 x 1050 screen on my left
- Giving a talk with a projector: 1024 x 768 screen, left or right
- At home, downstairs: 1280 x 1024 screen on my right
- At home, upstairs: 1280 x 1024 screen on my left

I find myself going into the Windows "Display Properties" dialog several times each day and manually resizing or repositioning the external monitor depending on my location. It would be great if there was some small utility that sat in the systray and provided me with a quick menu to switch between these display layouts. Does such a tool exist?

I am aware of UltraMon, which appears to have this functionality (along with many other features I don't need). However, I would be very excited to find a small **free** utility with just the display profile switching capability.

Comment: Which graphic card do you have in your laptop?

Answer (score 2):

my recommendation:

> **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)** provides advanced, multi-monitor, programmable hardware
>   support to a wide range of graphics
>   cards - from the venerable ATI Mach 64
>   to the latest Matrox Parhelia-LX and
>   Radeon 9800. It is in fact the only
>   program of its type to support
>   multiple graphics cards from multiple
>   chipset vendors, simultaneously, under
>   every Windows operating system from
>   Windows 95 to XP. A simple menu that
>   pops up from the system tray provides
>   access to some 500 controls over your
>   display hardware, including
>   sophisticated color correction tools,
>   period level adjustments over screen
>   geometry, and driver independent clock
>   controls.

just create multiple profiles for each scenario.

*Powerstrip is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: Nice but not free, as requested! ;-)

Comment: i know, but a killer app nonetheless and well worth the little money ($29.95) they're asking for. some folks do code for a living, you know. :)

Comment: I know, I code for a living too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with [**Presentation Director**](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-67364) from Lenovo? I have problems downloading it now (issue with my Internet connection) so I cannot try and see if it works with other computers than Lenovo's (maybe your laptop is a Lenovo?).

[image]

There is a blog article describing its features [here](http://lenovoblogs.com/insidethebox/?p=128).

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I'd want, although oddly enough I get a BSOD on my Lenovo when I try to configure custom settings.