# Multiple display switching

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

At work I have 3(rows)x4(columns) of displays, and I often have each row (of 4 screens) on a separate project. I am interested in flipping all of the windows in one row to another row - effectively switching the locations of these rows. Ie. I have project 1 on row 1, when I start on project 2 (on row 2) I would like row 2 and row 1 to switch rows.

I know this is probably impossible to do, but I will accept an answer that has a workaround or any info for enhancing screen utility for multiple displays.

My OS is Windows.

Comment: Related: [Easily switch between different multi-monitor setups (Windows XP)](http://superuser.com/questions/67669/easily-switch-between-different-multi-monitor-setups-windows-xp?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 great, I had not seen this.

Answer (score 2):

An option that works well in windows is [Displayfusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/).
They [support 10+ monitors](http://www.displayfusion.com/News/2012/07/how-many-monitors-does-displayfusion-support/).

[Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) is a non-free option that will allow you to set separate display profile configurations and monitor arrangements that you can switch to and from using hotkeys or a system tray icon.
It also allows you to populate taskbars on each monitor with the programs that are running.

[Ultramon's FAQ](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/faq.asp) has this to say about running 10+ monitors:

Maximum number of monitors
The maximum number of monitors isn't known, but the often-cited limit of 10 monitors is only a limitation of the Display Properties applet, not the system as a whole. So installing more than 10 monitors should work fine, but you would need a custom application, for example UltraMon, to configure them.

I have tested a 12-monitor Windows XP system with 3 Matrox G450 MMS quad cards, using UltraMon for configuration. Colorgraphic has built a 16-monitor system with Xentera GT cards, and expects to be able to run up to 64 monitors: see [this thread](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/messages.asp?Topic=3009) in their forums.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but just to note: UltraMon is a dead product.  DisplayFusion is much better and more capable these days, and still under active development.

Comment: Thanks, @Techie007 I haven't used ultramon in a while, and this might be why!