# Remove closed laptop screen from Windows desktop

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, desktop, lid

I have a Windows 10 laptop with an attached external monitor. The external monitor is set as the primary one.

In Power Options I have *When I close the lid* set to *Do nothing*, so that I can continue working on the external monitor, even when the lid is closed.

[image]

In Display Settings I have *Multiple displays* set to *Extend these displays*. This is good, when I need to use both the laptop display and the external display.

But when I close the lid, Windows still considers the laptop screen working and still extends my desktop to it. This causes problem with applications that start on the same display, where they were closed previously. If I have closed such application on the laptop screen before I closed the lid, the application will still start on the now-invisible screen.

My laptop is Asus G55VW and I see the same behavior on Lenovo Yoga 2 laptop. But it works as I want on HP ProBook laptop (the laptop screen is removed from Windows device manager when the lid is closed).

So I wonder if there is a setting to make Windows remove the closed laptop screen from the desktop? Or is it some driver-specific behavior that I cannot control?

Answer (score -2):

I was going to suggest WIN+P but XP is too old for that. Security wise using XP isn't really recommended at all unless you really have to.

Already answered here:
[Easily switch between different multi-monitor setups (Windows XP)](https://superuser.com/questions/67669/easily-switch-between-different-multi-monitor-setups-windows-xp)
Or this script/tool:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64968-toggle-external-monitor-on-and-off-on-a-laptop-in-windows-xp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using XP, but 10. I know Win+P, but I want Windows to do it automatically just as it is doing on my HP laptop.